# Windows-10-IOT QT-C++/QML App Fullscreen Gui Frozen when monitor turns back on

Tags: user-interface, qml, fullscreen, freeze

**ISSUE:**

On a touch panel with no keyboard, my QT C++/QML app running on Windows 10 IOT has the fullscreen GUI "frozen", when the monitor turns on (after the user has triggered the touchscreen), after it has timed-out earlier and turned off due to power settings. Mouse cursor still updates.

The QML GUI has "flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window"; I do not want to add "Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint" as it will block the control panel window when it is open from the app. The program is verified to be still running, only the GUI has frozen from the point in time when the screen turned off.

**TEMPORARY RESOLUTION:**

The only way to "unfreeze" the fullscreen GUI is to connect a keyboard & press the Windows key to show-hide the start menu, or do it programmatically with a manual QML button placed at a known position or on detection of monitor WM_POWERBROADCAST messages.

When the app is not fullscreen, the freezing doesn't seem to be happening.

Is this due to some missing WM_MESSAGES (e.g. WM_PAINT, WM_ACTIVATE, etc) sent by the OS to the app when it is fullscreen, or when the start menu button is pressed?

Can the app-fullscreen-freezing on monitor-turn-back-on be rectified by the app programmatically sending a sequence of WM_MESSAGES to itself, but not the Win button keypress (as the normal user is not supposed to access the OS or see anything related to the OS when the app is running)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem with a Desktop application on two different machines, except the freeze happens both in fullscreen and in windowed mode.

Updating the drivers seems to have solved the issue on one of the machines, but not the other one (they have different graphics chipsets), so it might be worth a try but it's not a guaranteed fix.

So instead I monitored WM_POWERBROADCAST as you suggested, quickly toggling the window visibility when the monitor is turned back on. Because the window is not refreshed between the toggles, this workaround does not seem to produce any flickering or artifact.

The Windows event management is handled in a dedicated class `WindowsEventFilter`.
`WindowsEventFilter.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef WINDOWSEVENTFILTER_H
#define WINDOWSEVENTFILTER_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <powrprof.h>
#include <QAbstractNativeEventFilter>
#include <QWindow>
#include <QGuiApplication>

class WindowsEventFilter : public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
public:
    WindowsEventFilter(QGuiApplication& app, QWindow& window);
    ~WindowsEventFilter() override;

    // Overrides the nativeEventFilter method to handle events
    bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result) override;

private:
    // Handle for power events
    HPOWERNOTIFY _hPowerNotify;

    // GUID for monitor power on event
    GUID _guidMonitorPowerOn;

    // Main window
    QWindow& _window;
};

#endif // WINDOWSEVENTFILTER_H
```

`WindowsEventFilter.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "WindowsEventFilter.h"

WindowsEventFilter::WindowsEventFilter(QGuiApplication& app, QWindow& window)
    : _window(window)
{
    // Installs the filter to the app
    app.installNativeEventFilter(this);

    // Defines the GUID for monitor power on event
    _guidMonitorPowerOn = {0x02731015, 0x4510, 0x4526, {0x99, 0xe6, 0xe5, 0xa1, 0x7e, 0xbd, 0x1a, 0xea}};

    // Registers for power events
    _hPowerNotify = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(HWND(_window.winId()), &_guidMonitorPowerOn, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
}


WindowsEventFilter::~WindowsEventFilter()
{
    UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(_hPowerNotify);
}


bool WindowsEventFilter::nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
{
    // Windows events
    if (eventType == "windows_generic_MSG")
    {
        MSG* msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);

        if (msg->message == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
        {
            if (msg->wParam == PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE)
            {
                const POWERBROADCAST_SETTING* pbs = reinterpret_cast<const POWERBROADCAST_SETTING*>(msg->lParam);
                if (pbs->PowerSetting == _guidMonitorPowerOn)
                {
                    DWORD dwMonitorState = pbs->Data[0];
                    switch (dwMonitorState)
                    {
                    case 0: // Monitor off
                        break;
                    case 1: // Monitor on
                        if(_window.isVisible())
                        {
                            // Quickly toggles the window visibility so QT realizes that the window is visible and should keep being updated.
                            // Circumvents a QT bug where in some cases (related to hardware/drivers), after Windows turns off the monitor due to user inactivity,
                            // the window UI remains frozen after turning the monitor back on.
                            _window.setVisible(false);
                            _window.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Filters out the message
            *result = 0;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Other messages are not filtered
    return false;
}
```

Then, you just need to instantiate it in the `main` after loading the QML in the engine:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "WindowsEventFilter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Loads main.qml
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.addImportPath(":");
    engine.load(url);

    // Intercepts Windows events to circumvent a QT bug (must be done after loading the QML so the root window exists).
    QWindow* window = engine.rootObjects().isEmpty() ? nullptr : qobject_cast<QWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().first());
    if (!window) throw std::exception("Could not find the root window.");
    WindowsEventFilter filter(app, *window);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using winAPI SetForegroundWindow() function...?

:-( Fast forward a few days...

With further testing, it seems that using SetForegroundWindow() alone is not consistent/reliable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

The most reliable that works is still the VK_LWIN keypress sent by the app. But, as mentioned before, the app user is not supposed to see the start-menu appearing then disappearing. Best if the behavior of the VK_LWIN keypress could be duplicated to the app without seeing the start-menu...